# Clearcase snapshot view path's not resolving when comparing

Tags: windows, version-control, diff, clearcase

We use Clearcase at my work and I have several snapshot views setup (on Windows XP).  The views themselves seem to work great, however whenever I try to compare any versions of any elements from my snapshot view, I have problems with my diff tool (currently Beyond Compare).  Specifically, if I'm comparing with previous, I see the current version great, but the previous version never shows up in the diff tool.

I've looked into the problem a bit and looking at the command line that is getting passed into the diff tool, CC is passing in a bad path to the file.  The path to the file that is not working looks something like this:

```
//server/path/to/viewstorage.vws/....
```

The problem appears to be in the **//server** used to access the SMB share where the file is found.

Where is CC getting this bad path from?  Is this something specific to how my snapshot view is setup (this worked for a long time and still works on some of my co-worker's machines)?  Is there any way to change this path to the typical `\\server` that Windows expects?

### Update:

Ok, so my original question was written from home, and wasn't entirely accurate.  The actual path is more like this:

```
//server/path/to/vobstorage.vbs\....
```

To answer [@koslorr question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083580/clearcase-snapshot-view-paths-not-resolving-when-comparing/4083811#4083811), the global path for the view is correct (the view is actually stored on a public share on my machine), however doing the similar command for the vob (`cleartool lsvob -l /my-working-vob`) does show that the global path for the VOB is incorrect.  Can this be updated in a similar way to the view tag?  Is this something my CC admin is going to need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check your view Global Path with

```
cleartool lsview -l <VIEW TAG>
```

Is the Global Path in the correct \server.... form?

If it is not, then you can use

```
cleartool mktag -view <VIEW TAG> -replace...
```

to change it to the correct form.

cleartool man mktag should tell you more in details.

Answer (score 0):

What a `cleartool diff -pred myFile` gives you when executed in your snapshot view path?

```
cd c:\path\to\my\snapshotView\myVob\path_to_myFile
cleartool diff -pred myFile
```

If the global path is incorrect, it can be because of:

- an incorrect mktag ([`cleartool man mktag`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktag.htm)), as [kolslorr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389615/kolslorr) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083580/clearcase-snapshot-view-paths-not-resolving-when-comparing/4083811#4083811). Don't forget to specify the host of the view storage as well as its global path (see ["Renaming a ClearCase VOB or View"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21124390))
- an [incorrect region](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/rgy-admin.htm) (see your ClearCase control panel): the view might be correctly defined in another region